# Unable to publish the page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a blank web part page and a custom web part. I have added that web part into the page. After all the changes when i tried to check in and publish the page, the page again goes in edit mode and i am unable to publish the page. I was able to check in the page from the designer but cannot publish the page. I have a list web part on that page which is connected to my custom web part. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: sounds a bit vague. you should be able to publish pages by going to the Pages library and use the contextual menu. as for why you can't publish directly, must be some environmental issue, maybe browser related, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom MasterPage? If yes Can you please change it to OUT of box Master and perform publishing?

Can you check the ULS log and Advise ?